# Передать данных с cardview в фрагменте в другой фрагмент при клике

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Как я могу отправить следующие данные в другой фрагмент, когда нажму на него: 
- `card_title`, `card_image`, `card_text`.

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на этот `card_view`, более детально открыть эту карту в новом фрагменте. Как я могу это реализовать?

**Главный фрагмент:**

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements IdeaListApadter.ItemClickCallback {

    private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRAS = "BUNDLE_EXTRAS";
    private static final String EXTRA_QUOTE = "EXTRA_QUOTE";
    private static final String EXTRA_ATTR = "EXTRA_ATTR";
    IdeaListApadter listData;

    public CategoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idea_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        IdeaListApadter adapter = new IdeaListApadter(
                new String[]    // this card_title
                        {"Изготовление мебели",
                        "Мини детский сад",
                        "Продажа мороженого",
                        "Организация праздников",
                        "Аренда квартир",
                        "Печатный центр"},
                new int[]   // this card_image
                        {R.drawable.mebel,
                        R.drawable.minidetsad,
                        R.drawable.morozhenoe,
                        R.drawable.prazdnik,
                        R.drawable.arenda,
                        R.drawable.pechat},
                new String[]    // this card_text
                        {"Несмотря на то что в каждом городе имеется большое количество мебельных магазинов, бывают случаи, когда люди приходят в данные предприятия и не могут найти то, что им действительно нужно. Когда средства позволяют, хочется сделать в квартире эксклюзивный ремонт и обставить ее дорогой, изысканной и практичной мебелью. В некоторых случаях это могут быть даже индивидуальные заказы со своими эскизами. Именно поэтому есть смысл открыть цех по производству мебели.",
                        "Детский клуб – прибыльный бизнес-проект, набирающий все большую популярность. Несмотря на высокую конкуренцию, детские развлекательные центры способны приносить своим владельцам серьезную прибыль. Главное в этом деле – создать оригинальный, практичный и доступный клуб, в котором дети будут чувствовать себя как дома.",
                        "Самое сложное и, пожалуй, невозможное в открытии бизнеса по торговле мороженым — организовать ларёк. Это, как минимум, год проволочек в инстанциях перед тем как открыться. Сразу учитывайте это предупреждение, если думаете собрать документы за пару месяцев. Это дюжина муниципальных ведомств, где необходимо собрать разрешения и согласования.\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "Поэтому игроки рынка советуют остановиться на двух последних вариантах. Торговать мороженым более чем выгодно — розничная наценка доходит до 200%. Летом бизнес по торговле мороженым выходит в ноль за несколько по-настоящему жарких дней. Поле чего начинается работа на себя.",
                        "Наверняка вы уже слышали о существовании таких фирм. Эти фирмы берут на себя все хлопоты организации праздников. При этом ассортимент услуг, которые предоставляют такие агентства, очень разный. От полной организации торжества, куда входит поиск ресторана или кафе, развлекательная программа, составление меню и т.д., до отдельных услуг – предоставление программы или ведущего и т.д..",
                        "Сдача квартир в аренду сегодня для многих казахстанцев стала бизнесом, причем довольно прибыльным. Высокие цены на недвижимость и дефицит жилья позволяют предполагать, что потенциал этого вида деятельности еще достаточно велик.\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "Когда владелец квартиры только задумывается о том, чтобы начать сдавать свою недвижимость, он не знает многих правил ведения этого бизнеса. Например, новички часто задают вопросы, нужно ли регистрироваться в качестве ИП и что случится, если прописать клиента в своей квартире? Также многие до сих пор уверены, что составление договора аренды вовсе не обязательно. Конечно, можно обойтись и без него, но надо знать, что вы при этом теряете. К тому же многие не понимают, где границы прав и обязанностей арендатора либо арендодателя.",
                        "Каждый из нас когда-то был студентом или учеником школы и знает, сколько времени приходится тратить на то, чтобы «отксерить» нужную страницу книги или чего-то другого. Это просто пытка, когда вы стоите в очереди по полчаса, просто ради того, чтобы сделать ксерокопию. Всем небезызвестна эта животрепещущая тема. К тому же вспомните свои посещения разных государственных (и не только) инстанций, типа БТИ (Бюро Технической Инвентаризации) или налоговой, где справки или иные документы необходимо размножать и распечатывать в бесчисленных объемах, а сделать это обычно негде. И потому все вынуждены искать организации, которые именуются копи-центрами.\n" +
                                "Это такие точки, где можно быстро и недорого сделать необходимое количество копий тех или иных документов. Даже в наш век компьютеризации они остаются популярными и востребованными. А организовать такую точку под силу практически каждому. Ведь этот бизнес не требует больших вложений и может стать неплохим источником постоянного дохода."});

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);
        listData =  adapter;
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int p) {
        CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt();    // Further as?
    }
}
```

**Адаптер**

```
public class IdeaListApadter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IdeaListApadter.MyViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDatasetTitle;
    private int[] mDatasetImage;
    private String[] mDatasetData;

    private ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

    public interface ItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClick(int p);
    }

    public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
        this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView textViewTitle;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewData;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            textViewData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDetail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.cont_item_root) {
                itemClickCallback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public IdeaListApadter(String[] myDataset, int[] ints, String[] strings) {
        mDatasetTitle = myDataset;
        mDatasetImage = ints;
        mDatasetData = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public IdeaListApadter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.idea_card_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(mDatasetTitle[position]);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mDatasetImage[position]);
        holder.textViewData.setText(mDatasetData[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDatasetTitle.length;
    }
}
```

**Второй фрагмент**

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView ideaTitle, ideaData;
    ImageView ideaImage;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.idea_detail_layout, container, false);
        ideaTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
        ideaData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idea_detail);
        ideaImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);

        return view;
    }

    public void change(String textTitle, String textData, int image){
        ideaTitle.setText(textTitle);
        ideaData.setText(textData);
        ideaImage.setImageResource(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала меняете сигнатуру коллбэка:

```
void onItemClick(String cardTitle, int cardImageResId, String cardText);
```

Далее меняете вызов коллбэка:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.cont_item_root) {
        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
        itemClickCallback.onItemClick(mDatasetTitle[pos], mDatasetImage[pos], mDatasetData[pos]);
    }
}
```

В классе `DetailsFragment` добавляете константы:

```
private static final String CARD_TITLE_KEY = "CARD_TITLE_KEY";
private static final String CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY = "CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY";
private static final String CARD_TEXT_KEY = "CARD_TEXT_KEY";
```

и фабричный метод:

```
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(String cardTitle, int cardImageResId, String cardText) {
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(CARD_TITLE_KEY, cardTitle);
    bundle.putInt(CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY, cardImageResId);
    bundle.putString(CARD_TEXT_KEY, cardText);
    detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return detailsFragment;
}
```

Далее, в методе `onCreateView(...)` во фрагменте `DetailsFragment` можете получить переданные значения с помощью метода `getArguments()`.

Comment: Добрый вечер, можешь ли подробнее сказать. что то не получается. если честно я не очень знаю куда что написать и как написать getArguments. https://vk.com/dossanovbeka